# What exactly are these chips?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman-1984

We see these chips in Diana's home:

[image]

What exactly are these chips?

Comment: Those look like the type of 35 mm [photo slides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversal_film) that would be used in an old school [slide projector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slide_projector).

Comment: I agree. You should enter that as answer.  The slides could also be viewed in a handheld viewer, which is more likely in someone's home.    https://www.picclickimg.com/d/l400/pict/174214932441_/Vintage-Boots-The-35-40-Viewer-Hand-Held-Slide.jpg

Comment: Those are pictures. My father was a photographer. I grew up surrounded by them

Comment: Randy, you've make a certain percentage of users feel REALLY OLD right now....

Comment: Haha (ha...) to think someone would have to ask about that... I feel so old. I'll console myself listening to some cassettes... ;-P

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As noted by LogicDictates, those look like [photo slides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversal_film), a technique involving turning photographs into positive image transparencies that can be viewed either using a [projector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slide_projector) to shine light through them and project them on a wall, or via a [slide viewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slide_viewer).

My personal experience with such slides involves a much flimsier casing of cardboard, but they could also be more durably encased in metal or plastic.

[image: Cardboard slides] [image: Metal slides] [image: Plastic slides]

Comment: The metal ones are rare in my experience, but plastic is another common alternative, and looks to be what are in the original image.

Comment: At the high end, slides which were likely to be projected in very-high-wattage projectors, like in big auditoriums, could be mounted between glass plates. Some conferences used to tell their presenters to make sure their slides were made like that.

Comment: I recently scanned some of my GFs old slides that were probably done in Europe back in the 1970s.  The processor had put the 35mm film in a two piece plastic frame (with glass covers) that snapped together.  They look like those in the OP.   Google "slide mounts"  I found several brands on Amazon and eBay.

Comment: It feels weird that you feel the need to explain what photo slides are. Am I really that old?

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I haven't seen a slide projector used in probably 30 years. We had an old carousel setup in the basement due to my mother keeping the supplies of a local organization that she worked for, and we occasionally broke it out to view the slides. Heck, I used the "Oops, upside down slide" on a Powerpoint a few years back, and the kids had no idea what I was referencing.

Comment: When I did my compulsory civil service 23 years ago in a teaching hospital, one of my duties was to run the slides for the professor's monthly lectures. And I did put them in the wrong way round multiple times. (Left and right lung always looked the same to me :-D) My parents still have an entire cabinet full of slides, although we haven't watched them in over a decade. We talked about digitizing them a couple of times but we never did. I think they are pretty degraded by now.